# ¿Cómo evito que mi scrollbar funcione al salir ventana emergente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que me gustaria hacer es bloquear la pantalla de mi sitio web, pero no toda solo la parte de atras, esto que quiere decir que cuando se abra mi modal la pantalla que esta atras de mi modal abierto no se pueda mover con el scrollbar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor agregue el código que tiene hasta ahora

Comment: ¿Tal vez `position:fixed` pueda ayudar?

Comment: @chun por el momento no tengo codigo aun, es que ninguno de los que eh encontrado por la red me convencia, porque todos me permitian el desplazamiento del scrollbar y me gustaria saber como evito ese desplazamiento

Comment: para evitar el desplasamiento se requieren 2 cosas, uno que el "contenido" que hace scroll no lo haga, se hace con overflow: hidden 
Después debes implementar un sistema que haga scroll sobre ese elemento en particular, es la unica forma de evitar que se siga moviendo.

Para "blockear" basta un div con position fixed y un backgraund.

Comment: Usas bootstrap?

Comment: @Gabriel Jeremy Rodriguez Rivers  si uso boostrap.

Comment: Has revisado mi respuesta, @David ? Ayudó a resolver su problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno, básicamente este es el concepto:

> Cuando el `lightbox` es **activado** `=>` bloquea el `body/html` *scroll*.
> Cuando es **desactivado** o se activa el **botón de cierre** `=>` agregue "*scroll* de cuerpo" de nuevo.

Ahora hay dos maneras de hacer esto.

✦ (nueva edición) Creando una clase con el estilo deseado para bloquear lo *scroll* de la página y alternar esta clase cuando necesario (que es la mejor práctica):

```
.block-scroll {overflow:hidden;}
```

✦ O añadiendo el estilo deseado directamente al elemento con `.css()`

```
$('html,body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

---

### 1. Creando una clase de manejo (nueva edición):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $popContainer = $('#popup-container');
    var $body = $('html,body');

    $('#fire-popup').on('click', function() {
        $popContainer.fadeIn();
        $body.addClass('block-scroll'); // clase de manejo
    });
    $('#popup-overlay').on('click', function() {
        $popContainer.fadeOut();
        $body.removeClass('block-scroll'); // clase de manejo
    });
});
```

```css
body {height:1000px;}
.block-scroll {overflow:hidden;} /* clase de manejo */
#popup-container {display:none;}
#popup-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    z-index:1;
}
#popup-overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.full-layer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fire-popup">Popup Trigger</button>
<div id="popup-container" class="full-layer">
    <div id="popup-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mattis non massa vitae mollis. Suspendisse at pellentesque lacus. Nunc ante quam, congue sed egestas quis, porta sed metus.
    </div>
    <div id="popup-overlay" class="full-layer"></div>
</div>
```

### 2. Añadiendo `.css()` para ocultar *scroll* directamente al elemento:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $popContainer = $('#popup-container');
    var $body = $('html,body');

    $('#fire-popup').on('click', function() {
        $popContainer.fadeIn();
        $body.css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });
    $('#popup-overlay').on('click', function() {
        $popContainer.fadeOut();
        $body.css('overflow', 'auto');
    });
});
```

```css
body {height:1000px;}
#popup-container {display:none;}
#popup-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    z-index:1;
}
#popup-overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.full-layer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fire-popup">Popup Trigger</button>
<div id="popup-container" class="full-layer">
    <div id="popup-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mattis non massa vitae mollis. Suspendisse at pellentesque lacus. Nunc ante quam, congue sed egestas quis, porta sed metus.
    </div>
    <div id="popup-overlay" class="full-layer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza este código para bloquear el scrolling a tu antojo

```
$("html, body").css("overflow","hidden"); <--- para ocultar

$("html, body").css("overflow","scroll"); <--- mostrar
```

Comment: Creo que `overflow block` no es realmente lo que estás buscando aquí Jose :P

Comment: mmm tienes razon xD ni idea en lo que estaba pensando lo voy a editar jajaj

Comment: gracias por la observación!